# TCPDF: Rotate Text / Cell in Table Header

Tags: tcpdf

I have some trouble with creating a table in TCPDF in which all header columns, except the first and last, should be rotated by 90 degrees (or: the text in that cells should be vertical).

Is there a way to rotate just the test within a cell, not the complete cell itself?

I want the table to look like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's simple one, Please check the following code.

```
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(-90);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'This is a sample data',1,1,'L',0,'');
$pdf->StopTransform();
```

Comment: When you work with MultiCell and give a width, after the StopTransform() the next cell starts as if the rotated cell were horizontal. It means there's a space between the rotated cell and the next horizontal cell. Do you understand what I'm trying to say ? X_X Help me pls!!

Comment: how can we do it in table's cell "td / th"?

Answer (score 6):

I'm working hard in this question in last 2 weeks.

The TCPDF tag works well when calling the Rotate method, but not that I wouldn't like.
My solution was:

1. Create a method to get X and Y for each  column with the TCPDF tag;
2. After writing a HTML table, you have to set the transformation Rotate of each column that you got, setting a new X and Y, depending of a page header;
3. To solve, if you have a header replication for each page of your multiple page table, I got the number of pages and set for each page the rotated text.

Now, the code example...

---

```
// Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    //Page header
    public function Test( $ae ) {
        if( !isset($this->xywalter) ) {
            $this->xywalter = array();
        }
        $this->xywalter[] = array($this->GetX(), $this->GetY());
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, 'A1', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set Rotate
$params = $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(90));

// other configs
$pdf->setOpenCell(0);
$pdf->SetCellPadding(0);
$pdf->setCellHeightRatio(1.25);

// create some HTML content
$html = '<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<thead>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<th rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center">ATIVIDADES E PROCESSOS</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center" valign="bottom">ASPECTOS</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">IMPACTOS</th>
<th colspan="3" width="6%" align="center">MEIO</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th colspan="9" width="18%" align="center">CLASSIFICA&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">PROGRAMA</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="10%" align="center">SUBPROGRAMA</th>
<th rowspan="2" width="15%" align="center">A&Ccedil;&Otilde;ES DE CONTROLE, MEDIDAS MITIGADORAS, COMPENSAT&Oacute;RIAS E POTENCIALIZADORAS</th>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<th align="center" height="200"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
<th align="center"><tcpdf method="Test" params="'.$params.'" /></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr bgcolor="#E6E6E6">
<td colspan="20" align="center">Planejamento</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td rowspan="3" width="15%" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Divulga&ccedil;&atilde;o do empreendimento</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%" align="left">Oferta de empregos diretos e indiretos</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="10%" align="left">Atra&ccedil;&atilde;o de popula&ccedil;&atilde;o para as comunidades do entorno</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center"></td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center"></td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">X</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center">AII</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">-</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Ind</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">T</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Mp</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">Po</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">D</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">R</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">M</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="2%" align="center">M</td>
<td rowspan="2" width="3%" align="center">M</td>
<td width="10%">Programa de Apoio ao Desenvolvimento Socioeconomico da Regi&atilde;o</td>
<td width="10%">Subprograma de Apoio ao Desenvolvimento Habitacional</td>
<td width="15%">Coibir ocupa&ccedil;&atilde;o indevida de &aacute;reas inadequadas</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td>Programa de Comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o Social</td>
<td> -</td>
<td>A&ccedil;&otilde;es de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o sobre o empreendimento e quest&otilde;es ambientais</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<td align="left">Gera&ccedil;&atilde;o de expectativas na popula&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
<td align="left">Gera&ccedil;&atilde;o de expectativas junto a popula&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center"></td>
<td align="center">X</td>
<td align="center">AII</td>
<td align="center">-</td>
<td align="center">Dir</td>
<td align="center">T</td>
<td align="center">Im</td>
<td align="center">Co</td>
<td align="center">L</td>
<td align="center">R</td>
<td align="center">P</td>
<td align="center">P</td>
<td align="center">B</td>
<td>Programa de Comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o Social</td>
<td> -</td>
<td>A&ccedil;&otilde;es de comunica&ccedil;&atilde;o sobre o empreendimento e questoes ambientais</td>
</tr>
</table>';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// array with names of columns
$arr_nomes = array(
    array("ABRANGÃŠNCIA", 8, 59), // array(name, new X, new Y);
    array("SIGNIFICÃ‚NCIA", 8, 59),
    array("FÃSICO", 4, 52),
    array("BIÃ“TICO", 4, 52),
    array("SOCIOECONÃ”MICO", 4, 52),
    array("NATUREZA", 4, 52),
    array("ORIGEM", 4, 52),
    array("DURAÃ‡ÃƒO", 4, 52),
    array("OCORRÃŠNCIA / TEMPORALIDADE", 4, 52),
    array("FREQUÃŠNCIA", 4, 52),
    array("ESPACIALIZAÃ‡ÃƒO", 4, 52),
    array("REVERSIBILIDADE", 4, 52),
    array("MAGNITUDE", 4, 52),
    array("RELEVÃ‚NCIA", 4, 52)
);

// num of pages
$ttPages = $pdf->getNumPages();
for($i=1; $i<=$ttPages; $i++) {
    // set page
    $pdf->setPage($i);
    // all columns of current page
    foreach( $arr_nomes as $num => $arrCols ) {
        $x = $pdf->xywalter[$num][0] + $arrCols[1]; // new X
        $y = $pdf->xywalter[$num][1] + $arrCols[2]; // new Y
        $n = $arrCols[0]; // column name
        // transforme Rotate
        $pdf->StartTransform();
        // Rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise
        $pdf->Rotate(90, $x, $y);
        $pdf->Text($x, $y, $n);
        // Stop Transformation
        $pdf->StopTransform();
    }
}

// reset pointer to the last page
$pdf->lastPage();

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: I had to accept the other answer since I wasn't using HTML tables. But I'm sure this is a decent solution, too. Thanks for that.

Comment: `Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0` can not find the reason.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old discussion but I'm still facing this issue. I have made a workaround on my TCPDF fork. http://sourceforge.net/u/mnicolardi/tcpdf/ci/master/tree/

I've added a parameter which informs MultiCell method that it is operating in a 90 degrees rotating environment. In this case it uses $h to move the cell to the right.

The new method prototype is:

```
public function MultiCell($w, $h, $txt, $border=0, $align='J', $fill=false, $ln=1, $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $stretch=0, $ishtml=false, $autopadding=true, $maxh=0, $valign='T', $fitcell=false,$rotated90Degrees=false)
```

Usage example:

```
 $pdf->StartTransform();          
 $pdf->Rotate(90);
 $pdf->MultiCell(100, 10, "rotated text", 1, 'C', false, 0, "", "", true, 0, false, true, 0, "T", false, true);
 $pdf->StopTransform();
```

Hope it helps!